tbl_uvregression no longer functioning with spaces in variable names
Since the latest update, my machine no longer is able to run tbl_uvregression when there are spaces in the variable names. This makes tons of my already existing code not run properly. Here is a reproducible example:
library(gtsummary)
names(mtcars)[2] <- "cyl but with spaces"
tbl_uvregression(mtcars, y = mpg, method = lm)

This yields the error message:
Error in tbl_uvregression():
! There was an error constructing the formula for variable "cyl but with spaces". See message below.
✖ :1:11: unexpected symbol 1: mpg ~ cyl but ^
Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred.

Hello! This bug was addressed recently and the fix is live in the development version of the package, which you can install with pak::pkg_install("ddsjoberg/gtsummary", dependencies = TRUE). Or you can revert to the v1.7.2 release until this fix is released on CRAN.

Perfect - thank you! Also I can't thank you enough for authoring this package. It has substantially improved my quality of life :)

If you're fine with changing the representation of the variable names only, you can:

    tbl_uvregression(mtcars, y = mpg, method = lm,
                     label = list(cyl = "cyl but with spaces")
    )


or roll your own function:

    tbl_uvregression_2 <- \(...){
      args <- list(...)
      data <- args[[1]]
      names_ori <- names(args[[1]])
      names(args[[1]]) <- make.names(names_ori)
      label <- names_ori |> setNames(nm =  names(args[[1]])) |> as.list()
      do.call(tbl_uvregression, c(args, list(label = label)))
    }

test:
    names(mtcars)[2] <- "cyl but with spaces"
    
    tbl_uvregression_2(mtcars, y = 'mpg', method = lm)




Thank you so much! The function you wrote is a nice workaround, but I am still wondering if this might be a bug in the latest gtsummary update. Additionally, when I add an "include" argument to the function you wrote I am getting an "object not found" error message.
tbl_uvregression_2(mtcars, y = 'mpg', method = lm, include = !c(hp))
